# Rails select2 ajax tags

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-select2, select2-rails

I'm using the select2 jquery gem. I'm trying to get the list of topics matching what the user types. It's not working as expected and i've spent all day trying to find out why. I keep getting this error in the console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toUpperCase' of undefined select2.js?body=1:363
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'localeCompare' of undefined
```

The second error links to the js file on this line

```
return this.text.localeCompare(term) === 0;
```

Is there something i'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

My route:

```
get '/topic/topic_list' => 'topic#topic_list'
```

In my Topic controller i have:

```
def topic_list
    @topics = Topic.order(:name)
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.json { render json: @topics.where('name like ?', "%#{params[:q]}%") }
    end
end
```

Topic js file

```
$(function () {
    $('#story_topic_list').select2({
        tags: true,
        width: '100%',
        tokenSeparators: [","," "],
        createSearchChoice: function(term, data) {
        if ($(data).filter(function() {
              return this.text.localeCompare(term) === 0;
            }).length === 0) {
              return {
                id: term,
                text: term
              };
            }
        },
        multiple: true,
        maximumSelectionSize: 5,
        formatSelectionTooBig: function (limit) {
            return 'You can only add 5 topics'

        },
        ajax: {
            dataType: 'json',
            url: '/topic/topic_list.json',
            data: function (term, page) {
                return { q: term };
            },
            results: function(data, page) {
                return { results: data };
            }
        }
    })
});
```

In my form i have

```
<%= f.label :topic_list %>
<%= f.text_field :topic_list %>
```

Also the /topic/topic_list.json returns this:

```
[{"id":2,"name":"app","added_by":null,"cover_id":null,"created_at":"2014-03-23T20:12:24.615+00:00","updated_at":"2014-03-23T20:12:24.615+00:00","count":1},{"id":5,"name":"app tech website","added_by":1,"cover_id":null,"created_at":"2014-03-23T20:23:33.754+00:00","updated_at":"2014-03-23T20:23:33.754+00:00","count":1},{"id":3,"name":"tech","added_by":null,"cover_id":null,"created_at":"2014-03-23T20:12:24.668+00:00","updated_at":"2014-03-23T20:12:24.668+00:00","count":1},{"id":4,"name":"website","added_by":null,"cover_id":null,"created_at":"2014-03-23T20:12:24.677+00:00","updated_at":"2014-03-23T20:12:24.677+00:00","count":1}]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The select2 does not know what field you want to use from the data you passed back. Assuming it is the `name` field, add this function separately (not in select2):

```
function format(item) { return item.name; }
```

and the two following options to select2:

```
formatSelection: format,
formatResult: format
```

Comment: And you may need to change `this.text.localeCompare(term)` to `this.name.localeCompare(term)` if you are still getting the localeCompare error

Comment: I see you're a rails guy as well, do you know how i can make the tags persist in the edit action? I've topic_list as an attr_reader to allow it to be called on forms.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help btw. I would have never gotten that.